# What is minimum size an app can use in split screen?

Tags: ios, ipad, accessibility

I have an accessibility app that I need to overlay over other apps. I've been informed that's not possible. So if that's true I'd like to know if I can make my app take 1/4 or 1/8 the screen in split screen mode. Ideally it should take as little space as possible. The other app is the main focus and mine is there for accessibility.

Is there a configuration I can set in my iOS app to indicate it take up only a quarter, eighth or sixteenth of the screen?

Comment: You have no control over this either. A user chooses how the two apps are laid out. Your app must work in full screen or one of the split screen sizes (if you choose to support split screen at all).

Comment: Is there no horizontal splitter on iOS? Meaning drag the center divider to increase or decrease the size of the left and right content panes?

Comment: The user can select your app to be an overlay or split screen 1/3,1/2 or 2/3. Split screen multitasking is only available on iPad, not on the iPhone.